# Points interpolation to a discrete Raster

Tags: python, gis, raster, gdal, qgis

I want to perform an interpolation (IDW or other) of points taking into account only discrete parts of the territory, such as different types of use or coverage, leaving others uncalculated?

Trying to do with QGIS or Python. The results I am not sure if the process followed is ok.

I have samples of points distributed throughout the territory with a series of indicators related to pollutants in soil. As it is not an interpolation of a phenomenon that is homogeneously distributed throughout the territory (such as temperature, for example), I am not sure which would be the best method to use.

[image]

**First question:**

With IDW and weight = 1 I obtain in some cases higher values than the points. Why it could be?

Natural soils raster:

[image]

When I perform the interpolation I obtain a continuous raster and then extract its values to the soil raster.

Continuos raster:

[image]

Extract values with raster calculator:

[image]

I want the interpolation to be distributed only in the areas where natural soil appears, for which I have a discrete raster (with gaps). Once I do the interpolation I extract the data from the continuous raster (interpolated) to the discrete raster (natural soils).

**Second question:**

Is it possible to do it taking in account only the pixels in the soils raster? Using QGIS and GDAL I am not sure how to do it.

I would prefer an opposite process, i.e. that the interpolation by distances is done only for the areas with natural soils (discrete raster). And not having to calculate areas where it is not necessary to have that information. Also, there may be areas that are close but have no continuity because they are in separate, non-contacting soil patches (regionalise the soil patches?). Any input is welcome.

Comment: Could you reduce this to a programming question? It looks interesting but seems like you just want opinions about your methodology.

Comment: Not sure about what you mean with "reduce" @Woodford. Must I add the technical description of steps of the process followed?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: done, changed the question and added more specific questions